# Cannot pass derived class to method that accepts generic base class

Tags: c#

Broadly i have the following code...

```
using System;

public interface ICommand<in TArgs>
    where TArgs : BaseArgs
{
    void Execute();
    void Execute(TArgs args);
}

public class BaseArgs
{ }

public abstract class BaseCommand<TArgs> : ICommand<TArgs>
    where TArgs : BaseArgs
{
    public void Execute()
    {
        var args = this.CreateArgs();
        this.Execute(args);
    }

    public void Execute(TArgs args)
    {
        this.GetData(args);
    }

    protected abstract void GetData(TArgs args);
    protected abstract TArgs CreateArgs();
}

public class ActualArgs : BaseArgs
{ }

public class ActualCommand : BaseCommand<ActualArgs>
{
    protected override void GetData(ActualArgs args)
    {
        var messenger = new Messenger(this.Execute);
        var m2 = new Messenger2(this);
    }

    protected override ActualArgs CreateArgs()
    {
        return new ActualArgs();
    }
}

public class Messenger
{
    public Messenger(Action caller)
    {
        caller();
    }
}

public class Messenger2
{
    public Messenger2(BaseCommand<BaseArgs> caller)
    {
        caller.Execute();
    }
}
```

Ideally i'd like to use `Messenger2` but the line in the `ActualCommand` complains that it cant cast `ActualCommand<ActualArgs>` to `BaseCommand<BaseArgs>`, i'd really rather not declare `Messenger2` as

```
new Messenger2<ActualCommand<ActualArgs>>(this)
```

Comment: is `public Messenger2(BaseCommand<ActualArgs>  caller)` acceptable?

Comment: No as i will have many Commands deriving from BaseCommand, each command will have its own Args object

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This doesn't work for two reasons:

1. Only generic *interfaces* can be made covariant (or contravariant). Your parameter is the abstract base class, not the interface.
2. Your interface is not (and cannot) be covariant.

Suppose this actually compiled - you'd be allowed to do this:

```
BaseCommand<BaseArgs> command = new ActualCommand();

command.Execute(new SomeOtherArgsDerivedFromBaseArgs());
```

This *must* give you some exception, as `ActualCommand` has no idea how to handle anything other than something that is or can be cast to `ActualArgs`.

Comment: Many thanks, that's annoyingly understandable now you've pointed out how it could be abused.